# Daily email limit - via workflow, Mass Email, Single Email

Tags: workflow, process-builder, limits, email-alert, mass-email

I am confused by what I read in document and what I saw in workbench.

[image: Salesforce Email Limit]

General Email Limit for email alert send through process builder/wprkflow:

[image]

In workbench I see the limits as below:

[image]

I am using a sandbox and trying to check the limits in the sandbox.In workbench I see mass email and single email limit as 5000, but documentation say it has to be 1000. daily email limit for workflow email alerts is 11000 from workbench but from documentation it should be # of user * 1000, in my sandbox I have following users only:

[image]

What I am missing here? Why such discrepancy here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the:

Its the number of **user licenses** * 1000 not active users.

Comment: understood now, Thanks. How about the mass email/ Single email limit which is shown as 5000. you think sales force increased my sandbox mass email limits?

Comment: @SfdcBat - Who knows. Stick to published limits and you should be fine. Even if the org has increased limits they could be changed at any time

Comment: I am working on a specific use case where I need to send mass email to around 10,000 external emails. If this limit was increased or can be increased it will make things easier for me. I do not have to purchase 3rd party app like Mass Mailer to do what I want to do, in this case sending out mass emails to around 10,000 external email ids.

Comment: @SfdcBat - You best bet would be a 3rd party app or marketing cloud. Its not just about the sending of emails. If it was I would question the need to send them at all. Other apps given you robust tools to monitor the effectiveness of the emails and ROI etc. SF is not meant to be a mass email system. Those do exist BTW. Sometimes SF is not the right tool by itself